# Как в SVG реализовать анимацию `туда и обратно`

Tags: html, svg

Есть такой пример

```html
<svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <style>
    circle {
        fill: url('#grad');
    }
    </style>
    <circle  cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="62" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="23%" stop-color="orangered" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="orange" />
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="y1" from="0" to="150" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Как реализовать анимацию, чтобы анимация шла от ***0*** до ***150*** и обратно к ***0***?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вместо `from="0" to="150"` необходимо использовать `values="0;150;0"`

```html
<svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <style>
    circle {
        fill: url('#grad');
    }
    </style>
    <circle  cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="62" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="23%" stop-color="orangered" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="orange" />
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="y1" values="0;150;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Для получения паузы между пограничными состояниями добавляется повтор значений. Арифмометр SVG делит поровну время `dur=5s` на количество значений, указанных в атрибуте `values` поэтому повторение значений приводит к увеличению времени выполнения на одной позиции, то есть фактически получается пауза.

```html
<svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <style>
    circle {
        fill: url('#grad');
    }
    </style>
    <circle  cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="62" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="23%" stop-color="orangered" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="orange" />
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="y1" values="0;75;150;150;75;0" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Значения values и время анимации подбирайте по своему вкусу

Comment: Вот черт... Вообще вылетело из головы..   Благодарю

Comment: @Air можно сделать паузу в конечном и начальном состоянии при переходах

Comment: Покажешь пример?

Comment: @Air без проблем

Comment: @Air, случайно не "0;0;150;150;0;0"?

Comment: О, я угадал! )))

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну что сказать.... Твои знания сродни компьютерной энциклопедии

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты как всегда...)))  Знаешь все..))) Кто бы сомневался...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а зачем ты 75 добавил? Это такая подгонка длительности шага?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, подгонка, не чётко видно было. Границы ведь зависят от `stop offset`` В примере ниже градиенты более контрастные, поэтому не пришлось этого делать

Answer (score 3):

### Дополнительные примеры анимация градиента

В этих примерах градиенты имеют более контрастные значения, поэтому легче отследить паузы в анимациях

**Анимация горизонтального градиента**

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
    <animate attributeName="x1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Для более интересного эффекта выбрал границы перекрытия отличающиеся от `50%`:

```
<stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
<stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
```

**Анимация вертикального градиента**

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**Анимация градиента под углом с паузами в конечных точках**

Анимируем сразу две координаты:

```
  <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
      <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate attributeName="y1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Связанный топик: [Создание CSS3 эффекта мигающего века](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/997604/28748)