# Создание CSS3 эффекта мигающего века

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь создать экран ожидания c цифрами обратного отсчета, который показывает глаз вместе с веком, и глазное яблоко с эффектом радужной оболочки.

Учитывая, что многие из нас бессмысленно проводят время, глядя на такие `лоадеры`, я хочу создать такой эффект лоадера, при котором  вращающийся "глаз" смотрит на зрителя и мигает.

```js
document.getElementById('waitDia').showModal();

var ticks = 300,
    ticker = setInterval(changeTick,1000);

function changeTick()
{
 document.getElementById('spnTick').innerText = --ticks;
 if (0 === ticks) clearInterval(ticker);
}
```

```css
#waitDia
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0 !important;
 top:0 !important;
 width:100vw !important;
 height:100vh !important; 
 padding:0; 
 min-width:100vw;
 min-height:100vh; 
 background-color:transparent !important;
}

#waitDia::backdrop{background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.2);}

#spnTick
{
 position:absolute;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 top:0;
} 
#waitbox
{
 left:0 !important;
 top:0 !important;
 width:100vw !important;
 height:100vh !important;
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
}


#eyeball
{
 position:relative;
 top:-10vh;
 left:-6px;
 width:calc(24vh + 12px);
 height:calc(24vh + 12px);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:rgba(0,128,128,0.5);
 border-radius:100%;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 18px 2px blue;
 z-index:99999998;
}


#waitsecs
{
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50vw - 12vh);
 top:46vh;
 width:24vh;
 height:24vh;
 font-size:8vh;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 
}

#waitEye
{
 position:absolute;
 top:27vh;
 left:calc(50vw - 23vh);
 width: 46vh;
 height: 46vh;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
 border-radius: 100% 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg); 
 mix-blend-mode:overlay;
 z-index:199999999;
 box-shadow:0 -0.5vh 0 2px #f1c27d,inset 0 6px 4px 4px black;
}
body,html
{
 background:black;
 font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<dialog id='waitDia' class='waitdia'>
   <div id='waitbox'>
    <div id='waitsecs'><span id='spnTick'>300</span><div id='eyeball'></div></div>
   <div id='waitEye'></div> 
   </div>  
  </dialog>
```

То, чего я смог достичь к настоящему времени, показано ниже - я установил здесь тикер на 300 секунд,  просто в качестве иллюстрации, чтобы он продолжал работать в течение долгого времени - в реальном приложении время ожидания, вероятно, будет значительно меньше.

Пока этот эффект движется в правильном направлении, но ему все еще не хватает эффекта моргания века. Я подозреваю, что это легко выполнимо с помощью правильной манипуляцией `box-shadow` и простой анимацией.

Я был бы очень признателен всем, кто мог бы предложить улучшения для завершения этой реализации.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Creating a CSS blinking eyelid effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56804355/7394871) от участника  [@DroidOS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077485/droidos).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56804355/7394871

Comment: Я выбрал этот топик для перевода из-за интересной авторской идеи в подходе к созданию лоадеров. Согласитесь, уже приелись в теме лоадеров всякие вращающиеся элементы. Опираясь на идею моргания глаз, в качестве лоадера, можно придумать много интересных решений. **Галочка и плюсы за оригинальные ответы гарантированы.** Жду новых ответов. Добавляю тег SVG, для расширения области ответов.

Comment: Добавлен вариант ответа [с обратным счётчиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997683/28748)

Comment: `Учитывая, что многие из нас бессмысленно проводят время, глядя на такие лоадеры, я хочу создать такой эффект лоадера, при котором вращающийся "глаз" смотрит на зрителя и мигает.` - повеселил....  ))))  Прикольно звучит...

Comment: @Air это же перевод, слова не мои, а автора вопроса  enso

Comment: Автоперевод ввёл ошибку:
"Я подозреваю, что это легко выполнимо с помощью правильной манипуляцией box-shadow и простой анимацией."  
Надо так: 
"..с помощью правильной манипуляции.."

Comment: @ Варлам Ерофеич  это стилистика и она целиком зависит от уровня переводчика, видимо ваш уровень выше .. Я технический смысл в перевода не исказил?  И то, что вы указали  `I suspect that` в переводе звучит однозначно - `Я подозреваю, что`  Мне было бы интересно увидеть от вас ваш вариант решения, в дополнительном ответе- вы это можете, я это знаю.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Двигаем 2 опорные точки в кривой Безье в зависимости от времени :

```js
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {

  // двигаем зрачок
  circle.setAttribute('cx', Math.sin(t/1000)*2);

  // анимируем градиент
  grad.setAttribute('offset', 40 + Math.sin(t/3000)*20 + '%');

  // сглаживаем время по формуле easeInOutQuint
  t = Math.max(0, Math.sin(t/300));
  t = (t<.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t)*6-3;
  
  // кривая Безье в зависимости от сглаженного значения времени
  let d = `-7 0C-2 ${t} 2 ${t} 7 0`;
  mask.setAttribute('d', `M-7 -7${d}L7 -7z`);
  eyelid.setAttribute('d', `M${d}`);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-10 -10 20 20" height="90vh">
  <defs><radialGradient id="g1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
      <stop id="grad" stop-color="teal" offset="30%"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
  </radialGradient></defs>
  <circle id="circle" r="2.4" stroke="black" fill="url(#g1)" stroke-width="0.2"></circle>
  <path id="mask" stroke="none" fill="white"></path>
  <path id="eyelid" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

---

```js
let rnd = (a, b) => (a||0) + ((b-a)||1) * Math.random();
let eyes = Array(22).fill(0).map((e, i) => ({
  i, 
  t: rnd(1, 10), 
  x: rnd(-96, 96), 
  y: rnd(-46, 46), 
  k: rnd(0.05,0.2), 
  r: rnd(-33,33)
}))

defs.innerHTML = eyes.map(e => `
  <radialGradient id="gradient_${e.i}" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
    <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
    <stop id="color_${e.i}" stop-color="hsl(${rnd(0, 360)},55%,35%)" offset="30%"/>
    <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <clipPath id="clip_${e.i}">
    <path></path>
  </clipPath>
`).join('');

g.innerHTML = eyes.map(e => `
  <g id="eye_${e.i}" transform="rotate(${e.r})scale(${e.k})translate(${e.x},${e.y})">
    <circle r="2.4" stroke="black" fill="url(#gradient_${e.i})" stroke-width="0.2" clip-path="url(#clip_${e.i})"></circle>
    <path stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
  </g>  
`).join('');

eyes.forEach(e => e.elements = {
  circle: document.querySelector(`#eye_${e.i} circle`),
  clipPath: document.querySelector(`#clip_${e.i} path`),
  eyelid: document.querySelector(`#eye_${e.i} path`),
  gradient: document.querySelector(`#color_${e.i}`)
})

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {

  eyes.forEach(e => {
    e.elements.circle.setAttribute('cx', Math.sin(t/100/(e.t+e.i))*2);
    e.elements.gradient.setAttribute('offset', 40 + Math.sin(t/300/(e.t+e.i))*20 + '%');
    let T = Math.max(0, Math.sin(t/50/(e.t+e.i)));
    T = (T<.5 ? 16*T*T*T*T*T : 1+16*(--T)*T*T*T*T)*6-3;
    let d = `-7 0C-2 ${T} 2 ${T} 7 0`;
    e.elements.clipPath.setAttribute('d', `M-7 3${d}L7 3z`);
    e.elements.eyelid.setAttribute('d', `M${d}`);
  })
  

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-20 -10 40 20" height="90vh">
  <defs id="defs"></defs>
  <g id="g"></g>
</svg>
```

PS: функция сглаживания взята отсюда: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

Comment: Не работает на планете, почему-то

Comment: @MaximLensky на чем чем?

Comment: я проверял на NextTab на Google Chrome последними обновлениями

Comment: @MaximLensky ошибки есть?

Comment: в яндэкс браузере работает на том же устройстве

Comment: @MaximLensky я сам то в хроме делал и проверял

Comment: я посте всегда проверяю в планшете и на смартфонах

Comment: @MaximLensky ну в сафари я тоже проверяю, но андроидов у меня нет

Comment: а у меня айпада уже нету, сына воду разлил но ремонтировать не буду и покупать тоже не хочу ..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997624/308951  на svg сделал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я одно не понял.Это что интерполяция внутри `querySelector` ? ` document.querySelector(`#eye_${e.i} circle`)`

Comment: @Demon__ANT нет, просто я тут использую шаблон строки для сборки `id`, тут `i` это просто индекс элемента

Comment: Хм.. Рожица из глаз: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2ywW.png

Comment: @Qwertiy планировал сделать чтобы они летели от центра, но не доделал пока :)

Answer (score 7):

Версия на Smil

```html
<svg width="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="translate(-8,-121)">
 <g id="eye">
  <ellipse cx="106.2113" cy="150.72321" rx="27.59226" ry="22.300594"/>
  <ellipse cx="108.47916" cy="149.58928" rx="10.205358" ry="8.3154764" fill="#fff"/>

  <animateTransform 
      attributeName="transform"
      attributeType="XML"
      type="translate"
      from="-5 0"
      to="5 0"
      dur="6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate 
       attributeName="fill"
       dur="3000ms" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       values="#1eb287;
               #1eb287;
               #1ca69e;
               #188fc2;
               #188fc2;
               #bb625e;
               #ca5f52;
               #1eb287;"/>
</g>
  <path d="" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="12" stroke-linecap="round">
     <animate 
      attributeName="d"
      dur="1.8s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      values= 
      "m195.79166 129.17857c-59.10423 2.90575-116.58946 5.9255-177.6488-3.02381;
       M 195.79166,129.17857 C 140.04024,174.83267 83.866918,194.57929 18.142857,126.15476;
       M 195.79166,129.17857 C 140.04024,174.83267 83.866918,194.57929 18.142857,126.15476;
       M 195.79166,129.17857 C 140.04024,174.83267 83.866918,194.57929 18.142857,126.15476;
       m195.79166 129.17857c-59.10423 2.90575-116.58946 5.9255-177.6488-3.02381;"
       keyTimes="0; 0.11; 0.21; 0.72; 1"
        /> 
    <animate 
       attributeName="stroke"
       dur="8000ms" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
      keyTimes="0;
             .0625;
             .208333333;
             .3125;
             1"
       values="red;
               green;
               blue;
               yellow;
               pink;"/>
  </path>
 </g>


</svg>
```

Comment: Работает на планке

Answer (score 7):

### Решение SVG SMIL

- Анимация века глаза достигается изменением атрибута "d" `<path>` с
  помощью перехода из верхнего положения вниз.
- Для реалистичности изображения века (придания объема) использованы
  радиальные градиенты
- Паузы в верхнем и нижнем положении века достигаются повторением
  позиций

  Более подробно об анимациях с паузами - [Как в SVG реализовать анимацию `туда и обратно`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994925/28748)

**Вариант решения без счётчика**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="25%" height="25%"   viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="40%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="45%" fy="20%">
   
   <stop stop-color="#B7B3B8" offset="10%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDC9D0" offset="65%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#9D90A2" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDBED3" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
 </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDG2U.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />

 <path id="veko" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#B9B5BB" stroke-width="4" d="m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z" >
 <animate attributeName="d" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;    
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;
   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z"    />
 </path>
</svg>
```

### Вариант с обратным счётчиком

```js
var checks = 100,
    checker = setInterval(Count, 2100);

  function Count() {
    document.getElementById('txt1').textContent = --checks;
    if (0 === checks) clearInterval(checker);
  }
```

```css
.container {
 background:silver;
 
}
svg {
display:block;
width:15%;
height:23%;
padding-left:0.5em;
padding-bottom:1.5em;
margin:1em;
border-radius:50%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
background:#8C6282;
}
#txt1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  fill:#FFDD00;
  stroke:#917E00;
  text-anchor:middle;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container"> 

<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="50%" height="50%"   viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs> 
  
 <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="40%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="45%" fy="20%">
   
   <stop stop-color="#B7B3B8" offset="10%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDC9D0" offset="65%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#9D90A2" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDBED3" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient> 
  <mask id="msk1" > 
   <path fill="white" d="M0.9 129.9C10.6 74.7 114.5 44.3 176.2 88.8c8 5.1 16.2 15.8 16.8 23.4C200 200 1.1 166.8 0.9 129.9" />
  </mask>
 </defs> 
 <g mask="url(#msk1)" >
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDG2U.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"   />

<text id="txt1" x="98" y="130"  >100</text> 

 <path id="veko" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#B9B5BB" stroke-width="1" d="m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z" >
 <animate attributeName="d" dur="2.4s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;    
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;
   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z"    />
 </path>
 </g>
 
 </svg> 
 </div>
```

Связанный вопрос: [Анимация svg глаз кролика с помощью атрибутов path “d” и “keyTimes”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/976005/28748)

Comment: @MaximLensky  неравномерность движения keyTimes про кролика помнишь :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976129/28748

Comment: @MaximLensky мне кажется такое многоцветье избыточно. Но, как говорится,- у каждого на вкус и цвет, свои фломастеры. Да и паузу для века, лучше сделать и в верхнем положении.

Comment: Саша а вот keyTimes задаётся только от меньшего к большему..а можно ли сделать разные Times ..к примеру не `0; 0.2; 0.3; 1;`  а `0; 0.6; 0.2; 0.4; 1;` вот так можно как не будь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Первое значение обязательно `0` последнее - `1` внутри диапазона могут быть любые значения, но общее количество должно быть равно количеству значений в `values` Для подбора значений  - [Генератор keyTimes](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1674)

Comment: а даже у тебя там в генераторе всё равно по возрастанию

Answer (score 5):

Я сделал бы это по-другому и рассмотрел бы вращение для получения эффекта мерцания. Трюк заключается в том, чтобы создать глаз с двумя элементами (веко), чтобы они имели возможность  моргать.

Вот код только с анимацией мерцания:

```css
.eye {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  perspective: 200px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% 250%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) top/100% 50%,
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% -150%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) bottom/100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat
}

.eye>div {
  height: 50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  animation:b1 0.8s  infinite ease-out alternate;
}
.eye>div:last-child {
  transform-origin:top;
  animation-name:b2;
}
.eye>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  padding-top:80%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -5px 5px 2px 4px black;
}
.eye>div:last-child:before {
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -6px -4px 2px 4px black;
}


body {
 background:#000;
}

@keyframes b1{
  to { transform:rotateX(-88deg);}
}
@keyframes b2{
  to {transform:rotateX(88deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Вот более реалистичное мигание век у всего глаза:

```js
var ticks = 300,ticker;
setTimeout(function() { ticker = setInterval(changeTick,1600);},500);

function changeTick()
{
 document.querySelector('.eye span').setAttribute('data-text', --ticks);
 if (0 === ticks) clearInterval(ticker);
}
```

```css
.eye {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  perspective: 200px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% 250%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) top/100% 50%,
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% -150%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) bottom/100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  position:relative;
}

.eye>div {
  height: 50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  z-index:1;
  animation:b1 0.8s  infinite ease-out alternate;
}
.eye>div:last-child {
  transform-origin:top;
  animation:none;
}
.eye>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  padding-top:80%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -5px 5px 2px 4px black;
  animation:inherit;
  animation-name:color;
}
.eye>div:last-child:before {
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -6px -4px 2px 4px black;
}
.eye > span {
  position:absolute;
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  bottom:18px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateZ(55px);
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20% 20% 0 0;
  z-index:2;
  animation:b2 0.8s  infinite ease-out alternate;
}
.eye > span:before {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:45px;
  width:100%;
  content:attr(data-text);
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:45px;
}


body {
 background:#000;
}

@keyframes b1{
  to { 
    transform:rotateX(-170deg);
  }
}
@keyframes b2{
  50% {
    height:20px;
  }
  60%,100% {
    height:0px;
  }
}
@keyframes color{
  0%,40% {
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:
      -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
      inset -5px 5px 2px 4px black;
  }
  40.1%,100% { 
    background:#f1c27d;
    box-shadow:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
  <div></div>
    <span data-text="300"></span>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Creating a CSS blinking eyelid effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804779/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Не сказал бы что сплющивание зрачка смотрится реалистично)

Answer (score 4):

Размер зрачка зависит от расстояния до мышки.

Глаз поворачивается в направлении указателя.

Процент загрузки выражается размером сектора радужной оболочки.

```js
let mouse = {x:0, y:0}, 
    progress = 0;
    
setInterval(e => progress = (progress + Math.random()/100)%1, 100)
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('pointermove', e => {mouse.x = e.x, mouse.y = e.y})

function draw(t) {

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  
  // двигаем зрачок
  let dx = mouse.x - innerWidth/2,
      dy = mouse.y - innerHeight/2,
      len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy),
      ml = Math.min(len*10/innerHeight, 1),
      a = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
      x = Math.cos(a) * ml, 
      y = Math.sin(a)/2 * ml;
      
  circle1.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle1.setAttribute('cy', y);
  circle2.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle2.setAttribute('cy', y);
  
  // процент загрузки
  let r = 1.8, 
      p = progress *2 * Math.PI, 
      px = r*Math.cos(p), 
      py = r*Math.sin(p),
      arc = 1-Math.round(progress);
      
  load.setAttribute('d', `M${r},0 A${r},${r},0,${arc},0,${px},${py}L0,0z`)
  load.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})`)
  
  // анимируем градиент
  let offset = Math.max(0.2, (0.5 - len/2/innerHeight))*100 + "%";  
  grad1.setAttribute('offset', offset);
  grad2.setAttribute('offset', offset);
  
  // сглаживаем время по формуле easeInOutQuint
  t = Math.max(0, Math.sin(t/300));
  t = (t<.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t)*6-3;
  
  // кривая Безье в зависимости от сглаженного значения времени
  let d = `-7 0C-2 ${t} 2 ${t} 7 0`;
  mask.setAttribute('d', `M-7 -7${d}L7 -7z`);
  eyelid.setAttribute('d', `M${d}`);
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0 calc(50vw - 50vh); overflow:hidden;">
<svg viewbox="-10 -10 20 20" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="g1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
        <stop id="grad1" stop-color="#4f899d" offset="30%"/>
        <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="g2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
        <stop id="grad2" stop-color="#885d33" offset="30%"/>
        <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <path id="load" fill="#fff"></path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="circle1" r="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2" fill="url(#g2)"></circle>
  <circle id="circle2" r="2" fill="url(#g1)" mask="url(#m1)"></circle>
  <path id="mask" stroke="none" fill="white"></path>
  <path id="eyelid" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
</body>
```